# Skrollr iOS issues

Tags: javascript, html, performance, webkit, parallax

I'm having issues with a parallax site I am building using Skrollr.

I've built a site that has the same effect as https://www.spotify.com/uk/. The effect being large full width background images that move slower than the natural browser scroll, and have text and other images moving on top of them.

When viewed on a desktop browser the site functions fine and performs perfectly. The problem I'm having is when testing on an iPad (iOS 6.1.3) and you release your finger from the screen and Skrollr's intertia animation takes over, the large background images and other content on the screen start to jitter and jump on the screen. This does not happen when you still have your finger touching the screen and scroll, only when you let go and the easing takes over.

A couple of things I've tried are:

- Setting `webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` on all of the background images, and skrollr-body div.
- Animate elements using `–webkit transition: translate3d`

If anyone could shed any light on why I'm getting this page flickering issue that would be great.

Comment: Does this happen as well when you call `animateTo` manually? Add a button to test this.

Comment: I fixed the issue by rolling back the Skrollr version to 0.5.14 (2013-04-04) which still uses iScroll? I'm thinking it must be to do with animation top position as opposed to webkit-transition: translate ? https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/182

Comment: Possibly. It would be great if you could open an issue on GitHub and help debugging it. Try using `top` as well, by replacing this line https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/src/skrollr.js#L562 (you need to make `#skrollr-body` `position:absolute` as well)

Comment: Done :) https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/249

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue (i.e. Skrollr / iOS parallax background image 'flicker'). I believe you'll find it's related to this: [cubiq.org/you-shall-not-flicker](http://cubiq.org/you-shall-not-flicker)

Simple solution (from the article): `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)`.